# Visual Studio Code starts spring boot application even if there are compilation errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I loaded up a spring-boot application into VS code. Everything looked good. And I go launch my "mainClass" file. Application launches fine. Everything is fine so far.

I make some code changes (not in the "mainClass" file though) to a random .java file in the codebase. Intentionally produce a compilation error. The open editor flags the (compiler) errors in the file. But when I launch the "mainClass" VS code starts the application as if there is nothing wrong.

What gives? How do I setup VS Code to not launch the mainClass if there are compilation errors?

EDIT: Another weird behavior I noticed:

**Scenario 1:**

1. Initial state: Spring boot project is in no-compiler-errors state.
2. Then, I edited a random .java file in the code base **within VS Code** and induced a compile error. Saved the file.
3. I confirmed the file was saved by opening it from OS file explorer.
4. Ran `mvn compile`. Maven does not detect the modified file and as a result reports BUILD SUCCESS.

**Scenario 2:**

1. Initial state: Spring boot project is in no-compiler-errors state.
2. Then, I edited a random .java file in the code base with some text editor of my choice and induce a compile error. Saved the file.
3. Ran `mvn compile`. This time maven **did detect** the modified file and reported BUILD FAILED with the compiler errors as expected.

This is in Mac OS.

Comment: How do you launch the class? Clicking the button **Run** in `.java` file or starting the project from Spring Boot DashBoard?

Comment: @MollyWang I tried launching the .java, using launch.json (which specifies mainClass) and also from Spring Boot Dashboard. Same behavior everywhere.

Comment: @Keerthi Java Debugger is used to pop up a notification to hint "Build failed, do you want to continue?". Now it doesn't appear and seems to duplicate with this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/949.

Anyway, even if we bring back this notification, you still have the option of continuing to start the main class. Java classes are loaded on demand in the JVM. Since your error is not from the main class, the main class can still be started just fine. The program will only complain about unresolved compilation errors if the error code is hit.